# Binary search recursive python

Tags: python, recursion, binary-search

im new to data structures and want to ask why is my binary search giving me an error.

I've tried running in the vsc terminal and gives me a syntax error. meanwhile,the problems tab isn't showing giving me any errors. would appreciate the pointers!

```
def binarysearch(list,value):
    if list == [] or (len(list)==1 and list[0]!= value):
        return False
    else:
        mid = list[len(list)/2]
        if mid == value:
            return True
        elif mid > value:
            return binarysearch(list[:len(list)/2],value)
        else:
            return binarysearch(list[len(list)/2+1:],value)

a =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
value = 7

if binarysearch(a,value):
    print("found")
else:
    print("none")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the lines that you call the recursion, the index to split must be an integer and not a float. Try the following code -

```
def binarysearch(list,value):
    if list == [] or (len(list)==1 and list[0]!= value):
        return False
    else:
        mid = list[int(len(list)/2)]
        if mid == value:
            return True
        elif mid > value:
            return binarysearch(list[:int(len(list)/2)],value)
        else:
            return binarysearch(list[int(len(list)/2)+1:],value)

a =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
value = 7

if binarysearch(a,value):
    print("found")
else:
    print("none")
```

Comment: integer division?

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your indexing part of code try using the `//` (integer division) symbol instead of division to get the approximate value after division and not a decimal (float):

```
def binarysearch(list,value):
if list == [] or (len(list)==1 and list[0]!= value):
    return False
else:
    mid = list[len(list)//2] # approximating the division to get an integer
    if mid == value:
        return True
    elif mid > value:
        return binarysearch(list[:len(list)//2],value)
    else:
        return binarysearch(list[len(list)//2+1:],value)
```

Comment: that symbol is called integer divison